# How to choose $x$ in order to make my sequence's limit -$\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence:

$a_n=2^n+\frac{x-2}{2}*n*2^n$

The question is, for what $x$ will this sequence have the limit -$\infty$, if $n \rightarrow \infty$?

It is obvious that if $x \ge 2$, the sequence is positive and therefore the limit is $\infty$.

How about if $x < 2$? Somehow the product on the right side should be bigger than $2^n$. If $x < 0$, I am sure that the right side will have a greater absolute value, but how about $ 0 < x < 2$? Is my reasoning good, or what would be the correct solution? Thanks.

Comment: For all $x<2$ the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n = 2^n(1 + f(x)\cdot n)$$

If $f(x) < 0$, then it is clear that the expression in the brackets will limit to $-\infty$, and being multiplied by $2^n$ will only accelerate the process.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=2^n(1+\frac {x-2}{2}n)$. For $x<2$ we have that $a_n \to \infty \cdot (-\infty)=-\infty$